# Android Fragment isAdded returns false after configuration change (screen Rotation)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an Activity with a ViewPager2. A ScreenSlidePagerAdapter is creating my 4 Fragments in the ViewPager. After sliding through the fragments `isAdded` returns `true` for every Fragment.
After a screen rotation configuration change `isAdded` returns `false` for all Fragments, but I have to keep them added. Is there a possibility to re-add them, or how can I keep them added?

UPDATE 1: after the configuration change `isAdded` is only `false` for all fragments which I slided through before the configuration change. For the other Fragments `isAdded` gets `true` also after the configuration change.

The Adapter code is:

```
    private inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity, data: Bundle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {
        val fragmentBundle: Bundle = data


        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            when (position) {
                1 -> { 
                    sliderFragment2.arguments = fragmentBundle                                  
                    return sliderFragment2
                }
                2 -> {
                    sliderFragment3.arguments = fragmentBundle
                    return sliderFragment3
                }
                3 -> {
                    sliderFragment4.arguments = fragmentBundle
                    return sliderFragment4
                }
                else -> {
                    sliderFragment1.arguments = fragmentBundle
                    return sliderFragment1
                }
            }
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return NUM_PAGES
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ViewPager2 automatically re-attaches the existing instances of the Fragments. It sounds like your `createFragment()` in your adapter is not actually creating brand new fragment instances? Please include your adapter code.

Comment: So what is `sliderFragment1`, etc? What are you doing with those fragments?

Comment: At the moment the 4 Fragments are just containin a TextView for testing purposes...

Comment: No, where do you create them, why do you hold onto a reference to them, etc.?

Comment: The fragments are created right just after class declaration:
class MyActivity : FragmentActivity() {
private var sliderFragment1: Fragment = SliderFragment1()
...

Answer (score 0):

```html
public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity{
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            //Use null, no restore
            super.onCreate(null);
            ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).